# How can I protect my CIFS attached shares from accidential deletion like 'rm -rf /'?

Tags: fstab, delete, cifs, shared-folders

I have a Synology NAS and I have 2 folders from it attached in `/mnt/nas-XXX` via `/etc/fstab` like so:

```
//192.168.178.100/BackUps /mnt/nas-backups cifs uid=0,credentials=/home/user/.smb,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,noperm    0 0
```

How can I protect them from accidential deletion like `rm -rf /` or others.

Comment: **Backup** everything that you cannot afford to lose.

Comment: Well, yeah, I do that. I just want some extra protection.

Comment: I have an alias for 'remove',  `alias rm='rm -i'` which makes it ask for confirmation. The alias can be escaped by `\rm ..`.

Comment: Do as much as possible with your standard user ID. Use sudo only when absolutely necessary and double-check before launching sudo commands.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be always aware of what you are typing, Although its not a scalable solution but it can help you To protect them from accidental deletion, You can add immutable attribute to files.

**chattr +i path_to_files**

Comment: Yea, that's one way, but I was thinking more along the line of applying something like that to `/mnt/nas-backups` no matter what I would do, `/mnt/nas-backups` would never be deleted unless I explicitly say YES or something.

I guess you can: https://www.tecmint.com/chattr-command-examples/ not just files, but folders too. But being immutable... does that mean nothing can be done to `/mnt/nas-backups`

Comment: If you set immutable on dirextory then you can not delete or modify the directory and its files , So, what else do you want?